# Creating model and index through one-line command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I know I can easily create a model with this one line. Now suppose I want to add an index on username. How can I do so with one line without going to edit the migration file manually?

```
script/rails generate model TwitterUser username:string num_followers:integer num_following:integer bio:string location:string image:string num_tweets:integer website:string
```

Comment: I'd really like the answer to this to be easy, but I don't think it is possible

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Rails version? New in 3.2, would be this:

`rails generate model TwitterUser username:string:index num_followers:integer ...`

You use `scrip/rails generate` so not sure if this helps you

Comment: Yes, as blogged by Jose Valim [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2/)